# Merging 2 Pandas Data Frames and

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 Pandas Dataframes say pd1 and pd2

```
pd1
x     y
0.0   1.2
0.2   1.4
0.5   2.6
```

pd2

```
x     y
0.0   1.5
0.3   4.6
0.8   2.4
```

I would like to merge these dataframes like this

```
x     y(pd1)  y(pd2)
0.0   1.2     1.5
0.2   1.4     NaN
0.3   NaN     4.6
0.5   2.6     Nan
0.8   NaN     2.4
```

Then I would like to scatter plot (x,y(pd1), y(pd2)) with different colors
Can you show me how to do it ?

Comment: You may ask one question in a SO post. As per the duplicate `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="x", how='outer')`

Comment: `ax = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y_x')` and `df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y_y', c='tab:orange', ax=ax)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to achieve this. The parameter `on` chooses the column to join on and `outer` makes a union of `x` values from different `pd`

```
merged = pd.merge(pd1, pd2, on='x', how='outer')
```

Comment: Many thanks Trenton. Is there a way to create 2 seperate column like I have in example above ? Just merge the x values and keep 2 seperate y'x ?

Comment: @RajatMitra, Try this
merged = pd.merge(pd1, pd2, on='x', how='outer',suffixes=('_x', '_y'))#"_x" for left df, "_y" for right df

Comment: Many thanks Venkat!  That worked....